# How to show custom text in Notification in Android

Tags: android, android-broadcast, android-broadcastreceiver

I want show **telephone number** when **call ringing** in `Notification`, but I don't know how can I show **Telephone number** in `Notification`!
For Telephone Number i `BroadcastReceiver` and i can show this number in `RecyclerView`, but i want show number in `Notification`!
**My Receiver codes:**

```
public class NumberReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {

            String number = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);

            DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
            SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            dbHelper.saveNumber(number, database);
            database.close();

        }

        Intent intent1 = new Intent(DBContract.UPDATE_UI_INTENT_FILTER);
        context.sendBroadcast(intent1);
    }
}
```

**MainActivity codes:**

```
    public class Prabeesh_page extends AppCompatActivity {

        private RecyclerView Prabeesh_LIST;
        private TextView Prabeesh_TEXT;
        private Adapter mAdapter;
        private ArrayList<IncomingModel> list = new ArrayList<>();
        private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_prabeesh_page);

            Prabeesh_LIST = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.prabeesh_list);
            Prabeesh_TEXT = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.prabessh_textView);
            Prabeesh_LIST.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
            Prabeesh_LIST.setHasFixedSize(true);
            mAdapter = new Adapter(list);
            Prabeesh_LIST.setAdapter(mAdapter);

            readFromDB();

            addNotification();

            broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                    readFromDB();
                }
            };

        }

        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();

            registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(DBContract.UPDATE_UI_INTENT_FILTER));

            readFromDB();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            super.onPause();

            unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
        }

        public void readFromDB() {
            list.clear();
            DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
            SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = dbHelper.readNumber(database);
            if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    String number;
                    int id;
                    id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("ID"));
                    number = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContract.INCOMING_NUMBER));

                    list.add(new IncomingModel(id, number));
                }
                cursor.close();
                dbHelper.close();
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                Prabeesh_LIST.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Prabeesh_TEXT.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }

        private void addNotification() {
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
                    new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                            .setContentTitle("Notifications Example")
                            .setContentText("This is a test notification");

            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, Prabeesh_page.class);
            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

            // Add as notification
            NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            manager.notify(0, builder.build());
        }
    }

**With this codes i use numbers in `RecyclerView` :** 
ublic class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<IncomingModel> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public Adapter(ArrayList<IncomingModel> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.prabbesh_row, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.ID.setText(Integer.toString(list.get(position).getId()));
        holder.NUMBER.setText(list.get(position).getNumber());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView ID, NUMBER;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            ID = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.prabeeshRow_ID);
            NUMBER = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.prabeeshRow_NUMBER);
        }
    }
}
```

How can i show this number, in `Notification`?

Comment: Do you mean putting the number in your Notification using the .setContentText("This is a test notification");?

Comment: @snowman28924, yes my friend. can you help me? please

Comment: Ok, why don't you move the addNotification() method to the NumberReceiver class and show the notification from there once the receiver is called,  you should be able to, since you have a context there.

Comment: @snowman28924, can you send me code? I am amateur. Tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class NumberReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    Context context;
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    this.context = context;

    String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
    if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {

        String number = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
        addNotification(number)
        DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
        SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        dbHelper.saveNumber(number, database);
        database.close();

    } 

    Intent intent1 = new Intent(DBContract.UPDATE_UI_INTENT_FILTER);
    context.sendBroadcast(intent1);
} 

private void addNotification(String number) { 
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                        .setContentTitle("Notifications Example") 
                        .setContentText(number); 

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, Prabeesh_page.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

        // Add as notification 
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        manager.notify(0, builder.build());
    } 
}
```

I just added the addNotification method with a String parameter, and then called it from the onReceive method passing the number from the incoming call.

Comment: Thank you my dear friend